# printf function in c

Tags: c, printf

here are part of my code.

```
float a = 12.5;
printf("%d\n", a);
printf("%d\n", (int)a);
printf("%d\n", *(int *)&a);
```

when I compile in windows, I got:

`0
12
1094713344`

and then, I compile in linux, I got:

`-1437851864
12
1094713344`

`-1437851864` will be changed every time I excuted it.
my question is: in how does the "printf" function works in linux

Comment: Using the wrong format code in printf triggers undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works very well, but why are you passing the wrong sort of data to it? The `%d` specifier expects and `int`, but you're passing something else. Bad idea.

If `float` and `int` are differently sized across the varargs barrier, this is undefined behavior. And since  `float` is [typically promoted to](http://c-faq.com/varargs/float.html) `double` with varargs calls, if your `int` is smaller than your `double` this will break.

In short, this is really bad and broken code. Don't do this.

Comment: thanks a lot! It is really a bad and broken code, but from the code,  I know that "printf" will be different between linux and windows.However, what is the difference?

Comment: It is undefined behavior. It's up to the compiler, what to do here.

Answer (score 3):

To print a floating point number in C, you should do:

```
float a = 12.5;
printf("%f\n", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, passing arguments with types not matching the format string invokes undefined behaviour, so the language standard doesn't place any restrictions on what

```
float a = 12.5;
printf("%d\n", a);
```

actually does.

To find out what it does, you'd need to analyse your implementation, or at least the assembly the compiler produced for that code.

A common way for translating that code is to pass the promoted (to `double`) `float` argument in a floating point register and tell `printf` how many arguments are passed in floating point registers. But since the format tells `printf` to look for an `int`, it doesn't look in a floating point register for it, but in another register. So the printed value would be whatever happened to be in that register when `printf` was called.